# Integrating Android profiling monitor into Appium script

Tags: android, testing, automation, profiling, appium

I'm looking for a way to perform profiling (memory, cpu..) on my tested app (right now only Android profiling is needed).

Currently, I can only do this manually, by opening Android Studio and using its built-in profiling tools whenever I perform a test.

I was wondering if there was any way to integrate these tools into the Appium automation script, in order to scale-out the profiling to many devices and many test variations, and to save precious time.

Alternatively, if anyone knows of a similar tool that can be integrated into Appium I'd love to know about it.

Answer (score 0):

For memory profiling, you can always pull down the "perflib" package in the Android Studio source. That is a more-or-less standalone package (with a couple of dependencies from within the sdktools parent package, which are standalone). The code in com.android.tools.perflib.heap is what you want, and that has all the methods to open an Android HPROF and process it.

As for other resources (CPU and whatnot), look at the viewers associated with them in Android Studio source (com.android.tools.idea.monitor), and look at the interactions with ClientData or adb commands used to fetch that data.

Comment: The reason I am considering using Appium is that it can be used to run through our entire app and taking profile dumps at key points. Any reason why this is not a good approach. And if it is a good approach then can anyone share experience please?